# True 1px table border in FireFox?

Tags: css

FireFox has problems with `border-collapse: collapse;`, line thickness randomly changes even at 100% zoom. This was the only thing I could think of to create a table with 1px borders everywhere. But this is ugly. Is there a better way?

```css
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

table td {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what about this: [https://jsfiddle.net/n00du841/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/n00du841/1/)

Comment: This is the same as mine in a compact form, no?

Comment: Ok I'm out, I've got nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, although causes problem when dynamically hiding table columns in Angular.

```
table {
    font-size: inherit;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

td, th {
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    vertical-align: top;
    min-width: 10px;
    empty-cells: show;
}

table.border td, table.border th {
    border-left: solid 1px #808080;
    border-top: solid 1px #808080;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: none;
}

table.border tr th:last-child, table.border tr td:last-child {
    border-right: solid 1px #808080 !important;
}

table.border tr:last-child th, table.border tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #808080 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/n00du841/

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is a 2px border both in Chrome and FF.

Comment: @Arthur Yes I didn't noticed that you asked for 1px. By ugly you mean table or CSS codes? Cause it seems to do the trick.

Comment: I meant the CSS. I'm also using a jquery based header freezing lib which works better on 1px borders. Its width calculations are a bit off in Firefox if the border is thicker.

Comment: @Arthur I've left a comment with a fiddle at your question, look at it. You sure it worth to use a jquery lib just for that?

Comment: Client wants fixed headers (list is several hundred lines long). And repeating the header, say, every 25 line doesn't look good on printing. So I created a hidden THEAD (shown in print only) and the jquery lib uses that to build a fixed header.

Answer (score 0):

Add border class to HTML table

```html
<table class="border">
```

Following CSS should work

```css
table.border {
    border-left: solid 1px #eee;
    border-top: solid 1px #eee;
}

table.border td, table.border th {
    border-right: solid 1px #eee;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #eee;
}
```